# How to use a load profile to calculate energy consumption

Tags: load, power-consumption, calculate

I usually receive electricity bills from the utility but due to issues on their end, they haven't sent me bills for the several months. Instead they gave me a load profile for a few months which has date time stamps in 15 min increments and some have numbers.
There's no headings on the columns so I don't know what unit of measure the numbers are.

How do I take these numbers and turn them into kWh? What information do I need to do this? I've googled how to do this but my calculations don't seem in line with past consumption so I think I'm missing something.

I want to know what information I need to calculate energy consumption for the past few months. Please explain to me like I'm five.

Average monthly consumption for this location is 4,200 kWh.

Here's a sample of a day's worth of data. The sum of column #2 =3,615

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Could you post a little of the information the electricity company sent you?  Hard to say much without looking at it!

Comment: Sorry about that. The csv file has a date/time stamp column and a column with numbers and that's it. 
Here's a sample of the first few rows. 
01.02.2023 00:15;0 72
01.02.2023 00:30;9 46
01.02.2023 00:45;9 72
01.02.2023 01:00;6 28
01.02.2023 01:15;0 34

I recognize this is not a lot of information to go on so part of my question is to understand what I need to ask from the utility if I need more information.

Comment: Much better if you edit it into your question.  If you put a whole day up it might show a pattern. Do you have any idea of how much energy your property uses for sense checking?  One way to get this is take your own meter readings (an hour apart, a day apart) which will be in kWh.  It's possible your CSV values are in kW averaged over the 15 minutes,  More likely is kWh used in that 15 minutes.

Comment: What’s the sum of column B for the day you listed?

Comment: Long shot: 30 ticks per kWh on your meter and column B is number of ticks per 15 minutes?

Comment: @winny -  I just updated the post with the sum of column B.

Comment: Assuming your day is average, (3615\*30)\*k=4200, your mystery scale factor k becomes 25.85.

Comment: BTW, knowing your electric *usage* will  not explain *billing*, which includes fixed charges for *delivery*, sliding cost per kW-h based on usage, etc. Almost as difficult to understand electric rates as cell phone rates!

Comment: At first glance it looked like the total (3615) was in kWh, close enough to your usual value of 4200, but it was for a day and not a month. The conversion factor would then be 30 (days/month). Illogical, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The table you're showing looks like CSV conversion gone wrong.

Look at this portion of the table:
[image]

The first cell contains a *date*, *time*, a *";" character* followed by another *numeric value*.

The second cell almost always contains a numeric value. Except for the timestamp 22:30.
It's also interesting to notice that this numeric value is always below 100.

I believe the raw CSV data of this portion looks as follows (or at least very similar):

```
01.02.2023 22:15;0,34
01.02.2023 22:30;2
01.02.2023 22:45;9,18
01.02.2023 23:00;17,14
```

Because of differing international locales, the CSV parser can use different characters as delimiters. Also the format to display decimal values could differ (for example `1.23` or `1,23`).

If in this instance your CSV parser interprets the **','** character as delimiter, instead of **';'**, it would result in a malformed output.

This would also explain why the second cell value is missing for the `01.02.2023 22:30` entry.

Now if we take that as a given, and reformat the data, you'll get something like this: (my locale uses the `1.23` format as decimal value)

[image]

NB: one entry is missing to complete the 24 hour period (either 00:00, or 24:00).

Comparing this total of `417.15` to the expected `4,200 kWh`, it looks to me like the unit of the mystery value is `[10 kWh]`.

If you'd upload the raw CSV data, we could confirm or reject this proposal.

---

For reference: the [CSV data](https://pastebin.com/PQFR34tt) of the converted table

Diagram for a plausibility check:
[image]